# C, C++ / Обнуление в структуре, указатель+адрес

Tags: c++, c

В с++ в структуре элементам присваивается ноль, а когда я пытаюсь сделать это в си, мне выдает ошибку, как можно исправить/заменить?

```
struct example {example *p=NULL;}
```

И еще один пример из с++, который не работает на си, когда вызываю функцию, выдает ошибку на "*&"

```
void function(spis *&h);
```

Comment: С - это не С++. Если вы в С не можете делать что-то, что можно делать в С++, то в этом нет ничего удивительного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C в отличии от C++ вы не можете в объявлении структуры указывать инициализаторы.

Поэтому данное объявление структуры

```
struct example {example *p=NULL;};
```

не будет компилироваться. Более того в C данное объявление также некорректно по другой причине: имя `example` не является именем структуры. Необходимо его предварить ключевым словом `struct`. Например

```
struct example { struct example *p; };
```

В принципе нет необходимости использовать инициализатор внутри объявления структуры. Вы всегда можете инициализировать соответствующие поля при создании объекта структуры или присвоить им значения уже после создания объекта структуры.
Например,

## include

В **C**:

```
struct example
{
    struct example *p;
};

int main( void )
{
    struct example list = { NULL };
}
```

Или

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct example
{
    struct example *p;
};

int main( void )
{
    struct example *list = malloc( sizeof( struct example ) );
    list->p = NULL;

    //...

    free( list );
}
```

Что касается этого объявления

```
void function(spis *&h);
```

то в C++ параметр является ссылочным типом на указатель типа `spis *` . В C ссылочные типы отсутствуют. Для большего понимания это объявление можно переписать следующим образом в C++:

```
typedef spis * T;
void function(T &h );
```

то есть параметр `h` - это ссылка.

Чтобы передать объект в функцию по ссылке в C, нужно передавать его через указатель на объект.

То есть вышеприведенную функцию следует объявить следующим образом

```
void function(spis **h);
```

Такая функция будет рботать в C и в C++.